# No Link to new App

Tags: openshift

Deleted an unscaled test app.
Recreated as scaled app under bronze plan.
Link to new scaled app does not exist but all git commands work.
Restart worked fine.
Still the link is "Not found on this server."
It has been an hour since recreation.
Thank you for any thoughts you may have.

Comment: 1)  When I use a web browser to go to the specified address, "the link is not found on this server" comes up as an error message. Same when I just click on the app's link on the app page on OpenShift.

Comment: 2) Git clone and Git update all work as expected.

Comment: Yes. Sure.  Will delete the existing one and then go through the creation process again.

App page says "Started" so I don't think this has to do with verifying a credit card.

Comment: Went through the delete/recreate process an hour ago. Same result. During the process there was an error message though, "Unable to complete the requested operation due to: Timed out while trying to fetch information from the nodes. Please try again and contact support if the issue persists. Reference ID: 4fcaffecd166a42b6f0bce9ec04445ab".

The error message went away after I retried the creation step but it makes me wonder if something is not completely right on the OpenShift side.

Comment: Yes.  Have done that just a moment before seeing your message. Will post whatever they say.

Comment: Yes indeed. Many thanks to all who responded. Feedback from OpenShift support was, "Try to force refresh the browser window (CTRL+ F5); if that doesn't work, try to clear the cache of your browser." I did both those things.

Answer (score 1):

Many thanks to all who responded. Feedback from OpenShift support was, "Try to force refresh the browser window (CTRL+ F5); if that doesn't work, try to clear the cache of your browser." I did both those things. Works fine now.

Answer (score 0):

That is probably a client-side cache issue, try to force your browser to request the updated page by or try to manually delete the cache.